# How to call a css properties inside plotLines in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to change the color of the plotLines through CSS. After click the print button the color of the plotLines should change to black. So after click the print button, will replace the previous CSS with a new CSS having 'Black' color.

Answer (score 0):

In the `beforePrint` and `afterPrint` chart events you can switch CSS classes for plot lines:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        beforePrint: function() {
            this.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].svgElem.addClass(
                'chart-plot-line-print-1',
                true
            );

        },
        afterPrint: function() {
            this.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].svgElem.addClass(
                'chart-plot-line-1',
                true
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o61yv97x/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#addClass

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#removeClass